# Why does nobody contact the police about the murder?

Tags: lateral-thinking

> Brian found himself sitting in a very large room with a solitary
>   light shining from behind him. He hears a voice say, "don't move."
>   Brian stays still. The voice starts again, "tell me why you're here or
>   I'll kill your friend." In front of him, Brian sees a familiar face,
>   and behind her he sees the man whose voice he heard. The man is
>   wearing armor which makes him seem larger than life, and he is holding
>   a gun that looks like it weighs a ton. Brian says nothing, and the man
>   again says, "tell me why you're here or I'll kill your friend." Brian
>   remains silent as the man shoots the person who Brian had known
>   for so many years. Brian seems unaffected by what just happened. He
>   sits for about an hour in silence, motionless, until the light behind
>   him goes dim. At that moment he calmly gets up, and leaves the room.
>
> The next day he tells his friends and coworkers what happened, but
>   nobody ever contacts the police about the murder. Why?

Comment: In the middle of the paragraph, it was mentioned as "... Brian says remains silent...". Perhaps a typo...or intentional...?

Comment: He has 911 rep. and the question mentions contacting the police illumanati confirmed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because

> He's seeing a film at a cinema, and the familiar face is the one of an actress.

Comment: you could say that "spoilers are not illegal"

Answer (score 3):

He's

> watching a film in a cinema. The solitary light is the projector. It goes dim at the end of the film.

Answer (score 2):

Another wild angle of it is - to say

> Brian is under hallucination/s, as usual, of which his friends/conacts/people around him are well aware of.

Answer (score 0):

> The red flag is that the man has unrealistic equipment. Brian might have fallen asleep, but noticed the flaw in the dream as he's a lucid dreamer.

Comment: What'd I do wrong?

Comment: Last time I checked, there's a lateral thinking tag.